# NDNI calculation - Band Names of MODIS

Tags: modis

[NDNI](https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/i-single.php?id=225) is an index that is designed to estimate the relative amounts of nitrogen contained in vegetation canopies. Reflectance at 1510 nm is largely determined by the nitrogen concentration of leaves, as well as the overall foliage biomass of the canopy. Together, leaf nitrogen concentration and canopy foliar biomass are combined in the 1510 nm range to predict total canopy nitrogen content. This is compared to a reference reflectance at 1680 nm, which should contain a similar signal due to foliar biomass, but without the influence of nitrogen absorption. ([https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/canopynitrogen.html#:~:text=Normalized%20Difference%20Nitrogen%20Index%20(NDNI,foliage%20biomass%20of%20the%20canopy.)](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/canopynitrogen.html#:%7E:text=Normalized%20Difference%20Nitrogen%20Index%20(NDNI,foliage%20biomass%20of%20the%20canopy.))

My question is which bands are designated for 1510nm and 1680nm in MODIS?

Answer (score 0):

MODIS does not have any bands that overlap those values. The closest is band 6, which has the range 1628–1652nm. You can see more here: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/data/get-started-data/collection-overview/missions/modis-overview/#modis-spectral-bands

Comment: Yes, I checked that's why I asked this question. How can I calculate it then?

Comment: @user14 you need to figure out a different way to approach your problem since calculating this index from the MODIS sensor is not going to work. Maybe a better question is: How to estimate leaf nitrogen from MODIS data?

Comment: ok I'll explore this, then. Thanks!